# Do I need to call admin.initializeApp at the top of each Cloud Function module file?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

My Cloud Functions for Firebase index.js is getting to the size where I'd like to start splitting the code file off into multiple module files.

However it's unclear whether I need to call this line at the top of each module/file which will be accessing the Firebase database.

```
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
```

Please excuse me if this is really obvious. I am not an experienced Node.js user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For all of the code in all of your modules that want to make use of the Firebase Admin SDK, you will need to have an initialized `admin` object available.  And in order to initialize the Admin SDK, you will need a `functions` object that comes from the following line:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
```

So, you could do this at the top of all your module files:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
```

And that would provide an initialized admin object for you to use in the functions defined in that file.  You can call the objects whatever names you want.

Alternately, you could figure out another way to get a single admin object into your code, but you have no obligation to do so.  It's completely up to you.

Comment: Thanks, so no downside to doing that then, that's just what I needed to know. I'll get refactoring then :)

Comment: This gives me: `Error: The default Firebase app already exists. This means you called initializeApp() more than once without providing an app name as the second argument. In most cases you only need to call initializeApp() once. But if you do want to initialize multiple apps, pass a second argument to initializeApp() to give each app a unique name.`

Comment: This is the wrong answer, look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52742434/do-i-need-to-include-admin-initializeapp-in-all-my-firebase-cloud-functions-f) instead

Comment: @conor909 Not sure what you mean.  These are both my answers.  The other one is specifically for TypeScript, and this one is for (old) JavaScript.  Your error message above could mean something not immediately evident from your code.

Comment: From my understanding you should not add `initializeApp()` at the top of all your module files.  Otherwise you get my error above.  You do it once in functions/index, and then you can reference `admin` in functions without initialising again so just `const admin = require('firebase-admin')` at the top of each file