# Do i need to include admin.initializeApp(); in all my firebase cloud functions file (Typescript)?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Question: If i'd like to use firebase services in separate function files, do i have to include `admin.initializeApp();` at the top of each file?

What is the current best practice of doing this?

I have a source folder containing 3 files

1. auth.ts - admin.initializeApp is at the top of this file
2. http.ts - Do i add it here if i want to use firebase services?
3. index.ts

My index.ts file is:

```
export { basicHTTP, advanceHTTP, api } from "./http";
export { createUserRecord } from "./auth";
```

My auth.ts file uses the admin.firestore():

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore();

export const createUserRecord = functions.auth
  .user()
  .onCreate((user, context) => {
    const userRef = db.doc(`users/${user.uid}`);
    return userRef.set({
      name: user.displayName,
      createdAt: context.timestamp,
      nickname: "bubba"
    });
  });
```

My http.ts file contains the following, what do i do if i want to use a firebase service within this function?:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

// Express
import * as express from "express";
import * as cors from "cors";

// Most basic http function

export const basicHTTP = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  response.send("Hello from firebase");
});

export const advanceHTTP = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const name = request.query.name;

  if (!name) {
    response.status(400).send("You must supply a name");
  }

  response.send(`Hi there ${name}`);
});

// Custom middleware

const auth = (request, response, next) => {
  if (!request.header.authorization) {
    response.status(400).send("Unauthorized. Access denied");
  }
  next();
};

// Multi Route ExpressJS HTTP Function

const app = express();

app.use(cors({ origin: true }));

app.use(auth);

app.get("/cat", (request, response) => {
  response.send("Cat");
});

app.get("/dog", (request, response) => {
  response.send("dog");
});

export const api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: Right now I'm only calling `admin.initializeApp()` in the index.js file and I haven't had any problems.  I'll still import the admin SDK in any files that use it. Also, all of my routing is done in the index.js file.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The first time you run this:

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
admin.initializeApp();
```

the `admin` returned from subsequent imports in other files will already be initialized.  This is because all imports from a module yield the exact same object.

If you want to use firebase-admin in multiple places, you could probably just import and initialize it once at your function entry point (index.ts), then assume in all the other places that it's already been initialized:

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
admin.initializeApp();
export { basicHTTP, advanceHTTP, api } from "./http";
export { createUserRecord } from "./auth";
```

Now you can simply import firebase-admin in your other modules and use admin without having to initialize it.

Comment: If I use this solution, I get the error `The default Firebase app does not exist. Make sure you call initializeApp() before using any of the Firebase services.` when deploying my functions. Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Okay, I already found my mistake. For all others:
Make sure you call `admin.initializeApp()` before you import your other functions. I missed this detail in the answer above.

Comment: @DanielS. this solved it for me, thanks!

Comment: In case anybody else hits this - 
In TypeScript I would get an undefined error if I had:
`import {initializeApp} from "firebase-admin"; initializeApp();` It needed to be like this post shows using `import * as admin from "firebase-admin"; admin.initializeApp();`

Comment: Thanks!  It's really not clear from the docs