# Why does using the "camelcase-keys" package cause a Firebase "initializeApp()" error?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to build some Firebase Cloud Functions, and also use the npm package [camelcase-keys](https://www.npmjs.com/package/camelcase-keys) to transform the keys of an API response.

But whenever use that imported package I get this error:

> Error: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to
> generate manifest from function source: Error: The default Firebase
> app already exists. This means you called initializeApp() more than
> once without providing an app name as the second argument. In most
> cases you only need to call initializeApp() once. But if you do want
> to initialize multiple apps, pass a second argument to initializeApp()
> to give each app a unique name.

This error is strange to me because I am following the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52743902/1526396) and only calling `admin.initializeApp()` once at my function entry point (`index.ts`).

Here is what the file structure looks like, and a copy of the code I am using.

Instead of including all the code, I have only included the salient parts (imports, exports, and admin.initializeApp). Let me know if more code pasted here would be helpful:

```
functions/
├─ src/
│  ├─ index.ts
│  ├─ dataForSeo.ts
```

**index.ts**

```TypeScript
import 'source-map-support/register';
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp();

export const sydneyFunctions = functions.region('australia-southeast1');
export const db = admin.firestore();

export {
  dataForSeoSerpGoogleOrganicDailyEnqueue,
  dataForSeoSerpGoogleOrganicTask,
  dataForSeoSerpGoogleOrganicPostbackUrl,
  dataForSeoOnPageStartCrawl,
  dataForSeoOnPageEnqueuePingbackUrl,
  dataForSeoOnPageGetResultTask,
} from './dataForSeo';
```

**dataForSeo.ts**

```TypeScript
import camelcaseKeys from 'camelcase-keys';
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import axios from 'axios';
import { getFunctions } from 'firebase-admin/functions';
import { DataForSeoGoogleOrganicPostTask, Serp, SerpItem } from './types';
import { getSecretVersion } from './googleSecretManager';
import { db, sydneyFunctions } from './index';

// Example usage
const test = camelcaseKeys(
  { 'foo-bar': true, nested: { unicorn_rainbow: true } },
  { deep: true }
);
functions.logger.info(test);

...
// Other functions below here
```

**UPDATE:**

Instead of using the `camelcase-keys` package I tried creating a recursive function using `lodash` that does the same thing.

This works without error:

```
import { camelCase, isPlainObject } from 'lodash';

const camelizeKeys = <
  T extends Record<string, unknown> | Record<string, unknown>[]
>(
  obj: T
): T => {
  if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
    return <T>obj.map((v) => camelizeKeys(v));
  } else if (isPlainObject(obj)) {
    return <T>Object.keys(obj).reduce(
      (result, key) => ({
        ...result,
        [camelCase(key)]: camelizeKeys(<T>obj[key]),
      }),
      {}
    );
  }
  return obj;
};
```

While this custom function is a work-around, I would still like to get the `camelcase-keys` package working.

Comment: What is `'source-map-support/register'` file?

Comment: It adds support for TypeScript stack tracing, so I can see which line of code the error is produced on. I have tested removing this. It has no impact. Read more here: https://github.com/evanw/node-source-map-support#typescript-demo

Comment: You have these 2 files only right? I wouldn't import `index.ts` in the other one. It like circular dependency otherwise. Can you keep `admin.initializeApp();` only in `index.ts` and then initialise `sydneyFunctions` and `db` in other file? Just don't import index.ts anywhere and don't use initializeApp() again.

Comment: I do have other files. They hold other functions I am exporting. But in none of those other files am I attempting to use the `camelcase-key` package. I did not include the other files to make the question more focused. If you think I should add them I will, but it will make it a very long question. Also as per your suggestion of not importing `index.ts` anywhere and instead initialising `sydneyFunctions` and `db` in their own files - that was my original setup - which I have reverted to now on your advice. But it has no impact. The error is still shown.

Comment: @Dharmaraj - my previous update to this question was incorrect. The custom function does work. I just accidentally left the `camelcase-keys` import in place when testing the custom function, causing the error to still show. When removing the `camelcase-keys` import and using only the custom function there is no error. I have edited the update to reflect that. Even though I have found this workaround I would still like to know why the `camelcase-keys` package does not work.

Comment: In [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52743902/15774176) , one this is missing  as mentioned in comment that " Make sure you call admin.initializeApp() before you import your other functions" , is it helpful? and can you specify the typescript version it will help in troubleshooting.

Comment: @DivyaniYadav In the `index.ts` file you can see I am calling `admin.initializeApp()` before import/export of my other functions. Also I am using TypeScript 4.5.4.

Comment: is this issue resolved now?

Comment: @DivyaniYadav no it is not.

Comment: @TinyTiger have you tried  checking for initialization as mentioned in the posted answer, does it worked?

Answer (score 2):

Had the exact same problem, I was following the Flutter Codelabs tutorial to implement IAP purchase (they use the in_app_purchase flutter library) verification into Firebase using Cloud Functions.

I got it working by downgrading the version used for camelcase-keys.

On your **package.json** file set camelcase-keys to version 6.2.2.

```
"camelcase-keys": "^6.2.2",
```

call **npm install** and then you should be able to deploy to firebase again.

Answer (score 0):

That is a truly a strange case.  I cannot say why it is occurring but to prevent re-initializing the app try this:

```js
if (!admin.apps.length) {
  admin.initializeApp();
}
```